# Access to openerp from the browser through amazon instance ip address ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ip, browser, openerp-7

everything looks fine in my installation but when I try to get into the openerp throug my browser, it says that it cant find the page….

2014-04-26 16:56:55,270 1307 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140425-231140

2014-04-26 16:56:55,271 1307 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons

2014-04-26 16:56:55,271 1307 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost

2014-04-26 16:56:55,271 1307 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432

2014-04-26 16:56:55,271 1307 INFO ? openerp: database user: openerp

2014-04-26 16:56:55,711 1307 INFO ? openerp.addons.google_docs.google_docs: GData lib 
version `%s GData-Python/2.0.18` detected

2014-04-26 16:56:56,062 1307 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections…

2014-04-26 16:56:56,064 1307 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069

That is what i get when i start the server…but when i put my http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8069 in my browser , it says the could not be find

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by default, the port 8069 is closed by amazon web services so we have to allow it. We need to go to the ec2 managing console, security groups and select a group click on inbound, add rule, select custom tcp tule and type 8069 and that´s it.